# Backbone.js add a computed attribute to model after it's parsed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In Backbone is there a way to execute a function on the model after that same model has been parsed.

I have models with base data, and want to compute another attribute of the combined base data.

Currently I have a function setup inside the model to create and add the attribute, this is executed after the data is fetched from server by looping through each model but it's not ideal.

```
var Report = Backbone.Model.extend({

    generateURL: function(){
        var sURL = '', sHash = '';

        sHash += this.get('reportid');
        sHash += 'p1' + app.venue.info.get('loginid');

        sURL += 'r=' + this.get('reportid');
        sURL += '&p1=' + app.venue.info.get('loginid');

        _.each(this.params, function(param){
            sURL    += '&' + param.name + '=' + param.value;
            sHash   += param.name + param.value;
        });

        sURL += '&h=' + new jsSHA((sHash + this.collection.sKey),'TEXT').getHash('SHA-1','HEX');

        this.set({"url":sURL});

    }

});

var Reports = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Report,
    sKey: '***********',
    url: function(){
        return '/reports/venue/'+ app.venue.info.id;
    },

});

app.venue.reports.set([{id:0,reportid:3,params:null,report_name:'Report3'},{id:1,reportid:2,params:null,report_name:'Report2'}]);

app.venue.reports.each(function(report){ report.generateURL(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can of course override the `.parse()` function and do whatever you wish.

```
var Mod = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(response){
        response.new_attr = response.old_attr + 1;
        return response;
    }
})
```

Comment: yes, but I want to get attr stored on model like id and also for them to be valid. Also thinking of using hasChanged to recompute the url.

Comment: another issue is that when u use Collection.set() the models parse is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Dazzer13, Stephen's approach is the correct one (that's one of the main use of the parse function).

For your first concern, whatever is returned by parse() will be used as the base data for your model. So assuming that your response contains:

```
{ 
  id: 1556,
  first_name: "John"
  last_name: "Doe"
}
```

You can use parse to modify this hash and add new computed values, for instance

```
parse: function(response) {
  response.initials = response.first_name[0]+response.last_name[0];
  return response;
}
```

Which will be exactly like creating your model with the following hash:

```
{ 
  id: 1556,
  first_name: "John"
  last_name: "Doe"
  initials: "JD"
}
```

It means that after that, you can do a model.get("initials") and it'll contain your computed value. And if you do a model.save(), it'll send initials in the data to the server: actually, internally Backbone always call a parse on a server's reponse, but the default parse just do a 'return response;'. That's why those new properties will be exactly like normal properties, because they go through the same mechanism as others.

For your second concern, it's true that calling a Collection.set() (or add) will not call parse... unless you give it the option {parse: true}! The reason for that is that a set() is supposed (at least based on the documentation) to be used for setting the collection with backbone models, not with javascript raw objects. The fact that it converts javascript raw objects to backbone models on the fly is more a convenience that anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try Alex Beletski's [backbone-computedfields](https://github.com/alexbeletsky/backbone-computedfields).
It's quite extensive and robust, handling events, changes, dependencies, JSON, and validation.  A quick example from the project page:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'netPrice': 0.0,
        'vatRate': 0.0
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.computedFields = new Backbone.ComputedFields(this);
    },

    computed: {
        grossPrice: {
            depends: ['netPrice', 'vatRate'],
            get: function (fields) {
                return fields.netPrice * (1 + fields.vatRate / 100);
            }
        }
    }
});

model = new Model({ netPrice: 100, vatRate: 20});
model.get('grossPrice')     // -> 120 is returned
```